# Nesting zones in Canada

Tags: geospatial, environment, biology, canada

Looking for spatial data for bird nesting zones in Canada:

[image]

Taken from [General nesting periods of migratory birds](https://www.canada.ca/en/environment-climate-change/services/avoiding-harm-migratory-birds/general-nesting-periods.html#_01_3)

Comment: You shoud find somewhere (perhaps [here](http://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/fe9fd41c-1f67-4bc5-809d-05b62986b26b)) spatial data for the so-called *ecodistricts*. Then JS code on [this page](http://www.birdscanada.org/volunteer/pnw/rnest/) (look into the Select Location tab) contains some data on which ecodistrict belongs to which nesting zone.

Answer (score 1):

[North American Breeding Bird Survey](https://www.pwrc.usgs.gov/bbs/) is what you'll most likely find useful; [BBS has two data options](https://www.pwrc.usgs.gov/bbs/RawData/Choose-Method.cfm).
[Migratory Bird Data Center](https://migbirdapps.fws.gov/) has [some more data](https://migbirdapps.fws.gov/mbdc/index.html) too.
[USFWS Migratory Bird Data Center](https://migbirdapps.fws.gov/)
[Breeding Bird Atlas data - USGS Patuxent Wildlife Research Center](http://www.pwrc.usgs.gov/bba/)
[Breeding Bird Survey data - USGS Patuxent Wildlife Research Center](http://www.pwrc.usgs.gov/bbs/)
All of these datasets include Canada, but here's [Candian specific data: ftp://ftpext.usgs.gov/pub/er/md/laurel/BBS/DataFiles/50-StopData/Pre1997_Canada/](ftp://ftpext.usgs.gov/pub/er/md/laurel/BBS/DataFiles/50-StopData/Pre1997_Canada/) for good measure.